# Find all the integer solutions $(p, q)$ of $p! = q^2 - 1$

Tags: number-theory

This felt like the sort of equation that goes like "there are 1 or 2 very small solutions and nothing else is possible," but after a bit of experimenting and coding, I've found $(4, 5)$, $(5, 11)$ and $(7, 71)$, so I started to wonder if there might be infinitely many solutions. I still think it's unlikely that there are, but proving it is beyond my ability. I couldn't really do much here, but am curious regardless (I'm somewhat new to Number Theory, this problem is a harder version of another one I found), so I wondered if anyone here could go further.

Comment: still unknown https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brocard%27s_problem

Comment: Welp, and I thought I was onto something cool. Thank you.